# SmtpCommandException: Invalid From address - <email@email.com>

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to implement functionality that sends email from web application. I am using mailkit. When I try to send email, I get this error "SmtpCommandException: Invalid From address - ". I searched everywhere for this error, but nothing found. I watched several video tutorials and I make the same steps, but the result was the same.

```
public void SendEmail(EmailViewModel model)
{
    var message = new MimeMessage();

    message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("SenderName", "Sender@email.com"));
    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Receiver@email.com"));
    message.Subject = model.Title;
    message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
    {
        Text = "Example email content)"
    };

    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
        client.Connect("smtp.abv.bg", 465);
        client.Authenticate("MyEmail", "MyPassword");
        client.Send(message);
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are swaping `address` and `displayName` fields, so it's checking if `SenderName` is a valid e-mail address, which is not.

Try changing:

```
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("SenderName", "Sender@email.com"));
```

To:

```
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Sender@email.com", "SenderName"));
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. The other thing is that when I try to send email like this "Receiver@email.com" to "Receiver@email.com" it works. Do I have to change something in sender email before passing it to MailboxAddress(), because I pass it only as string from my view model?